# SQL Server Linked Server Impersonate error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, linked-server, kerberos, impersonation

I'm trying to configure LinkedServer to use Impersonate.

All Servers and PC are connected to the same Domain.

What I've configured already:

SQLServer1 - First/Middle server:

- Configured SPNs for account that is running SQL services
- Configured delegation for account that is running SQL services
- Configured Delegation for server "Trust this computer for delegation to any service (Kerberos only)

SQLServer2 - SecondServer

- Configured SPNs for account that is running SQL services
- Configured delegation for account that is running SQL services (which I think is not needed but
  did it anyway)
- Configured Delegation for server "Trust this computer for delegation to any service
  (Kerberos only)(which I think is not needed but did it anyway)

Created LinkedServer on SQLServer1 to SQLServer2, in Security tab added AD account that is running SQLServices, added my AD Account and checked 'Impersonate' for both.

I've used Kerberos Configuration Manager to verify on both servers and it shows that everything is looking good.

**When I'm testing connection while I'm logged on SQLServer1 it passes.

When I'm testing it from my PC it returns Error:

"The test connection to the linked server failed. Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 18456)"**

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Verify that you're connecting with Kerberos. `select auth_scheme from sys.dm_exec_connections where session_id = @@spid`

Comment: Yes, I'm connecting with Kerberos.